# How to insert the missing categories into Panda DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

My panda DataFrame has two columns with CATEGORY and RESPONSE:

```
CATEGORY RESPONSE
0        0.0
1        0.5
2        0.111
3        0.01
5        
6
7
10
... etc 500 categories
```

For every missing category (here 4,8,9,...) I would like to insert an additional row into
DataFrame with the category value (here 4,8,9) and response 0 to get full 500 rows ordered
by category number.

What would be the most pythonic way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.set_index()` + `.reindex()`:

```py
df = (
    df.set_index("CATEGORY")
    .reindex(index=range(df["CATEGORY"].min(), df["CATEGORY"].max() + 1))
    .fillna(0)
    .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    CATEGORY  RESPONSE
0          0     0.000
1          1     0.500
2          2     0.111
3          3     0.010
4          4     0.000
5          5     0.000
6          6     0.000
7          7     0.000
8          8     0.000
9          9     0.000
10        10     0.000
```

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose we have the following dataframe with missing `CATEGORY` 4, 8 and 9 :

```
   CATEGORY  RESPONSE
0         0     0.000
1         1     0.500
2         2     0.111
3         3     0.010
4         5     0.800
5         6     0.900
6         7     0.181
7        10     0.100
```

**Proposed code**

```py
import pandas as pd

# Your original DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CATEGORY': [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10],
    'RESPONSE': [0.0, 0.5, 0.111, 0.01, 0.8, 0.9, 0.181, 0.1]
})


# Merge the original DataFrame with the new DataFrame using 'CATEGORY' as the key
df = (df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'CATEGORY': range(10)}), on='CATEGORY', how='right')
        .fillna(0)
        )
```

```
>>> df
   CATEGORY  RESPONSE
0         0     0.000
1         1     0.500
2         2     0.111
3         3     0.010
4         4     0.000
5         5     0.800
6         6     0.900
7         7     0.181
8         8     0.000
9         9     0.000
```